# turbo c & batch file

Tags: c, batch-file

My batch file is executing with c program but when I used start notepad.exe in batch file

it shows bad command .But when I execute my batch file individully it works perfect.What's

the reason?

Comment: can you post the code which launch the batch file, please ?

Comment: Can you show the code for the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post your bat file? It could be that the path to notepad.exe is relative to where you are running your bat file when you execute it manually, but when you call it from your C application you are running it from the C executable's location so it no longer finds either notepad.exe or a fiel that you may be passing to notepad.exe

Answer (score 0):

It must have to do with the path of your notepad.exe ,if you are on windows then try to add the path of notepad.exe to environment variable "PATH",that might simplifies lots of things.

Answer (score 0):

you say that you execute the batch file from the C program. are you sure the environment is properly setup when you start executing the batch file ?

if the PATH environment variable is not correctly set when executing the batch file, then the batch file will not execute. but the batch file will work without problem when launched from the command line, because the environment is correctly set in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`start` is an internal command of `cmd.exe`; it is not a program by itself. To run `start` you need to run `cmd.exe` and have that `cmd.exe` do the `start` thing.

The `system()` C function executes a shell (likely `cmd.exe` in Windows) and passes the argument to that shell -- and `start` "works".

The `exec*` functions do not load a shell -- and `start` by itself "don't work": it needs to be 'inside' `cmd.exe`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  // system "works"
  system("start C:\\tmp");

  // this don't work
  execl("start", "start", "C:\\Windows", (char*)0);
  printf("Oops: execl with start failed\n");

  // this "works"
  execl("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "start", "/c", "start", "C:\\Windows\\", (char*)0);
  printf("Oops: execl with <path>\\cmd.exe failed\n");

  return 0;
}
```